# x86 Linux assembler get program parameters from _start

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to create a program to just write the param on the screen.
I created some programs to get the C function parameter, or i used C to send the parameter to my asm program.
Is there a way to get the program parameter using only assembler

EX:

```
./Program "text"
```

I'm using as (Gnu Assembler)

Usually i get those parameters using

```
[esp+4]
```

Because the esp is the program/function call pointer, but in pure asm it don't get the command line parameter.

Is there a way to do that?

I googled it, but i wans't able to find much information

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On Linux, the familiar `argc` and `argv` variables from C are always passed on the stack by the kernel, available even to assembly programs that are completely standalone and don't link with the startup code in the C library.  This is documented in the [i386 System V ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI), along with other details of the process startup environment (register values, stack alignment).

At the ELF entry point (a.k.a. `_start`) of an x86 Linux executable:

1. **ESP** points to `argc`
2. **ESP + 4** points to `argv[0]`, the start of the array.  i.e. the value you should pass to main as `char **argv` is `lea eax, [esp+4]`, not `mov eax, [esp+4]`)

### How a Minimal Assembly Program Obtains argc and argv

I'll show how to read `argv` and `argc[0]` in GDB.

#### cmdline-x86.S

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>

    .global _start
_start:
    /* Cause a breakpoint trap */
    int $0x03

    /* exit_group(0) */
    mov $SYS_exit_group, %eax
    mov $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

#### cmdline-x86.gdb

```
set confirm off
file cmdline-x86
run
# We'll regain control here after the breakpoint trap
printf "argc: %d\n", *(int*)$esp
printf "argv[0]: %s\n",  ((char**)($esp + 4))[0]
quit
```

#### Sample Session

```
$ cc -nostdlib -g3 -m32 cmdline-x86.S -o cmdline-x86
$ gdb -q -x cmdline-x86.gdb cmdline-x86
<...>  
Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
_start () at cmdline-x86.S:8
8   mov $SYS_exit_group, %eax
argc: 1
argv[0]: /home/scottt/Dropbox/stackoverflow/cmdline-x86
```

#### Explanation

- I placed a software breakpoint (`int $0x03`) to cause the program to trap back into the debugger right after the ELF entry point (`_start`).
- I then used `printf` in the GDB script to print

  1. `argc` with the expression `*(int*)$esp`
  2. `argv` with the expression `((char**)($esp + 4))[0]`

---

## x86-64 version

The differences are minimal:

- Replace **ESP** with **RSP**
- Change address size from 4 to 8
- Conform to different Linux syscall calling conventions when we call `exit_group(0)` to properly terminate the process

#### cmdline.S

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>

    .global _start
_start:
    /* Cause a breakpoint trap */
    int $0x03

    /* exit_group(0) */
    mov $SYS_exit_group, %rax
    mov $0, %rdi
    syscall
```

#### cmdline.gdb

```
set confirm off
file cmdline
run
printf "argc: %d\n", *(int*)$rsp
printf "argv[0]: %s\n",  ((char**)($rsp + 8))[0]
quit
```

---

### How Regular C Programs Obtain argc and argv

You can disassemble `_start` from a regular C program to see how it obtains `argc` and `argv` from the stack and passes them as it calls `__libc_start_main`. Using the `/bin/true` program on my x86-64 machine as an example:

```
$ gdb -q /bin/true
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/true...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/true.debug...done.
done.
(gdb) disassemble _start
Dump of assembler code for function _start:
   0x0000000000401580 <+0>: xor    %ebp,%ebp
   0x0000000000401582 <+2>: mov    %rdx,%r9
   0x0000000000401585 <+5>: pop    %rsi
   0x0000000000401586 <+6>: mov    %rsp,%rdx
   0x0000000000401589 <+9>: and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
   0x000000000040158d <+13>:    push   %rax
   0x000000000040158e <+14>:    push   %rsp
   0x000000000040158f <+15>:    mov    $0x404040,%r8
   0x0000000000401596 <+22>:    mov    $0x403fb0,%rcx
   0x000000000040159d <+29>:    mov    $0x4014c0,%rdi
   0x00000000004015a4 <+36>:    callq  0x401310 <__libc_start_main@plt>
   0x00000000004015a9 <+41>:    hlt    
   0x00000000004015aa <+42>:    xchg   %ax,%ax
   0x00000000004015ac <+44>:    nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

The first three arguments to `__libc_start_main()` are:

1. **RDI**: pointer to `main()`
2. **RSI**: `argc`, you can see how it was the first thing popped off the stack
3. **RDX**: `argv`, the value of **RSP** right after `argc` was popped. (`ubp_av` in the GLIBC source)

The x86 **_start** is very similar:

```
Dump of assembler code for function _start:
   0x0804842c <+0>: xor    %ebp,%ebp
   0x0804842e <+2>: pop    %esi
   0x0804842f <+3>: mov    %esp,%ecx
   0x08048431 <+5>: and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x08048434 <+8>: push   %eax
   0x08048435 <+9>: push   %esp
   0x08048436 <+10>:    push   %edx
   0x08048437 <+11>:    push   $0x80485e0
   0x0804843c <+16>:    push   $0x8048570
   0x08048441 <+21>:    push   %ecx
   0x08048442 <+22>:    push   %esi
   0x08048443 <+23>:    push   $0x80483d0
   0x08048448 <+28>:    call   0x80483b0 <__libc_start_main@plt>
   0x0804844d <+33>:    hlt    
   0x0804844e <+34>:    xchg   %ax,%ax
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: One question: How can i do dword [ebp + 4 * ebx] in gas?

Comment: `(%ebp, %ebx, 4)` actually.  But you can always just assemble with `nasm -felf32` and disassemble with `objdump -d` to see how something is written in AT&T syntax.

Comment: Also a good idea: link to the ABI standard which specifies the initial process environment (i.e. what's in registers and memory before the first instruction of `_start` runs).  https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI currently links to [revision 252 of the x86-64 SystemV ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-r252.pdf).