# How to get the first command-line argument and put it into static buffer in memory?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I want to put into the buffer the first command-line argument which has length 4. I can get each char of it by :

```
.code64
.global _start

.bss

  .lcomm  mybuf , 4

.text
_start:

    mov   16(%rsp) ,  %rsi        #   argv[1]  
    movzx   (%rsi) ,  %ebx        #   first  char of argv[1]
    movzx  1(%rsi) ,  %ebx        #   second  char of argv[1]
    movzx  2(%rsi) ,  %ebx        #   third   char of argv[1]
    movzx  3(%rsi) ,  %ebx        #   fourth  char of argv[1]

  xor %rax , %rax
  inc %rax
  int $0x80
```

But how to put the whole string with length 4 into my buffer? My system is x64-Linux with GAS.

Comment: Have you tried something like `mov (%rsi), %ebx; mov %ebx, mybuf(%rip)`?

Comment: What are you trying to do to that string? Unless you want to modify it, you can use it where it is. `16(%rsp)` is its address, and it's null terminated already.

Comment: actually it is the file name and i want to make system calls write to /read from that file. and i cannot reach the stack memory with regs used in int 0x80  :-(

Comment: That's because `int 0x80` is for 32-bit system calls.  If you use `syscall` to make your system call, you can use 64-bit pointers and they can point to the stack or anywhere else you want.

Comment: By the way, usually people use the word "heap" to refer to dynamically allocated memory, e.g. `malloc`.  Here you seem to be trying to copy into `mybuf` which is a static buffer.

Comment: fuz: i tried  mov %ebx, mybuf(%rip) and it works for the first byte. but how to treat the second and so on?

Comment: @Ston17 That copies 4 bytes.  Isn't that what you asked for?

Comment: @Ston17 Note that you should really not use `int $0x80` in 64 bit code.  Instead, use `syscall` as Nate Eldredge said.  Note that both the system call numbers and the registers are different there.

Comment: fuz : what if i relocate my buffer ? is it possible to use %rip as base in that case? is it possible to use syscall in pure asm file - not inline asm in c? tnx

Comment: @Ston17 It doesn't matter if you relocate your buffer.  `mybuf(%rip)` is used instead of `mybuf` to generate a `rip` relative addressing mode.  `rip` is not a base register in the normal sense of the word.  Yes, you can use the `syscall` instruction from normal assembly.  It seems you have a great deal of confusion.  It might be better to start with an assembly tutorial instead of asking random questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to copy the contents of the string itself into a data buffer. Save the value of `16(%rsp)` in a QWORD sized variable and use it with syscalls all you want. In C terms, that would be the difference between

```
char lcomm[4];
strcpy(lcomm, argv[1]);
open(lcomm, ...);
```

and

```
char *plcomm;
plcomm = argv[1];
open(plcomm, ...);
```

The second one works just as well.

Also, your buffer has a fixed size of 4 bytes. If the command line argument is longer than that, your code will overflow the buffer, and potentially crash.

---

That said, if you're serious about learning assembly, you should eventually figure out how to write a `strcpy`-like loop. :)

---

EDIT with some assembly code. Last time I checked, the file name goes into the syscall as RDI, not RSI:

```
mov   16(%rsp), %rdi # File name
mov   $0, %rsi        # Flags: O_RDONLY, but substitute your own
mov   $0, %rdx        # Mode: doesn't matter if the file exists
mov   $2, %rax        # Syscall number for open
syscall
# %rax is the file handle now
```

---

For future reference, the x86_64 syscall convention is:

- Parameters go into %rdi, %rsi, %rdx, %rcx, %r8, and %r9 in that order
- Syscall # goes into %rax
- Then perform a `syscall` instruction
- The return value is in %rax
- %rcx and %r11 are clobbered, the rest of the registers are preserved

The reference of syscalls is [here](https://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/).

Comment: The C example was to illustrate the logic. See the edit anyway.

Comment: Do you know how to debug your assembly?

Comment: My bad, AT&T syntax isn't my native one.

Comment: `16(%rsp)` holds a qword pointer, not a dword.  In `_start`, it's `argv[1]` which is a `char*`.  Truncating a stack pointer to 32-bit would result in a segfault (or `-EFAULT` syscall return value).  Also note that `open()` returns an `int` fd.  It would be more accurate to say the FD is in EAX, not RAX.  (But you can check the full RAX for being -4095 .. -1, all Linux syscalls return error codes sign-extended to the full register width).

Comment: Oh, I think you mean copy the dword *pointed to* by `16(%rsp)`, now that I re-read the question.  The OP is talking about copying the string bytes after loading the pointer into a register.

Comment: You're right, I meant storing the *pointer* to argv[1], QWORD it is.

Comment: Yes, on entry to `_start`, RSP points at `argc`.  The entire argv array of values is right above that.  (`char *argv[argc]`, not `char **argv`).  Then, after the NULL terminator of `argv[]` is `envp[]`.  This process startup environment is documented in the x86-64 System V ABI. [x86 Linux assembler get program parameters from \_start](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16721164) shows the same thing for i386 SysV.

Comment: Yes the pointer is QWORD, but the OP is asking about copying the pointed-to data, so it's maybe confusing to talk about something else without being super clear on what value vs. pointer you mean.  The OP is talking about copying 4 bytes of string data from `argv[1]` to `char mybuf[4]`.  That's a dword copy.  (or 4x 1-byte copies the way the OP is loading them in the question).  The fact that it's a power of 2 size at all is just coincidence so maybe just say 4 byte if you mean the data, or don't talk about copying at all since you just need to load the pointer, not store the pointer in mem.

Comment: The OP was deeply confused. [S]he just wanted to pass `argv[1]` to `open`, that's it. No copying necessary. Meanwhile, I was not sure if the program would need `argv[1]` afterwards, thus all this talk of storing it.

Comment: You can reload it from `16(%rsp)` if you need it again.  Memory above RSP is yours and won't get stepped on.  I think the initial section about copying is a potentially confusing tangent at best.  It's your answer; if you like it then keep it.  But I wouldn't spend any time talking about copying something *else* (the pointer), other than what the OP was trying to copy.  Also BTW, `.lcomm mybuf, 4` defines `static char mybuf[4]`, not `char lcomm[4]`.  Your asm implements `open(argv[1], ...)` which is the sensible thing to do.

Comment: XY problem :) If you look at the question *as initially posed*, it was all about "how do I store argv[1] in my data".

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!

```
.code64
.global _start

.text

_start:

  mov   16(%rsp), %rdi  # File name from command-line first arg 
  mov   $0, %rsi        # Flags: O_RDONLY, but substitute your own
  mov   $0, %rdx        # Mode: doesn't matter if the file exists
  mov   $2, %rax        # Syscall number for open
  syscall
  mov %rax , %rbx

  mov $60, %rax
  syscall
```

tnx to Seva Alekseyev

Comment: We say thanks here by accepting and/or upvoting the answer.